# Scrolling with ScrollTo.js not functioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scrollto

I've been using scrollTo.js for a while now and everything worked great.

However, I decided to change the structure of my website files and now, scrollTo.js fires this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'scroll' on 'Window': 2
>   arguments required, but only 1 present.

Here is my HTML:

```
    <body class="scrolltoJS"> 
     <section id="1">
         <%content%>
        <div id="about_scroll" onclick="scroll('#clients')">
            <p>CLIENTS</p>
        </div>  
     </section>

     <section id="clients">
        <%content%>
     </section>
    </body>
```

Here is the JS

```
if($('body').is('.scrolltoJS')){    
        function scroll(parameter){
            $(parameter).ScrollTo();
        }               
    }
```

Here is my test landing page - http://aux.socialook.net/test_site/themes/index.html . Just click on the square button - Find Out More

Answer (score 1):

[window.scroll(x,y)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.scroll) is already defined so your code is trying to call that. My guess is that scroll function you defined is not being registered or you are defining it in another scrope that is not window.

Comment: Thank you, great viking espacarello :).

Not sure how this could be triggered just by changing the structure of the files or by adding the ifs for js triggering:

if($('body').is('.scrolltoJS')){    
        function scroll(parameter){
            $(parameter).ScrollTo();
        }               
    }

Comment: any ideas how to debug it?

Comment: When is `if($('body').is('.scrolltoJS')){` being called?

Comment: It's right after initializing 2 other js's (wow.js and stellar.js). So this is how my main js file begins - 

$(function(){
 
 if($('body').is('.wowJS')){  
     new WOW().init();
 }

        ++ stellar.js ++ scrollto.js

Comment: And the scroll function is in the wrong scope if it is defined the same way as above...Thank is why it is not registered....

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. The problem was that the scrollTO function was in another function that was firing initially but then wasn't available when calling the different functions in it.

code looked like this:

```
 $(function(){
     if($('body').is('.scrolltoJS')){    
         function scroll(parameter){
            $(parameter).ScrollTo();
         }               
     }
```